How to load bitcoin wallet from any wallet in regtest mode
I’m starting to code some stuff and need to get balance from wallets I generate using bitcoinjs-lib. When I hit my bitcoin server which is running in regtest mode it says that the wallet isn’t loaded or I need to specify the wallet on the jrpc request I’m making. Is there a way for the node to just return 0?
Are there better tools to help during development?
Thanks

Am I understanding right that you created a wallet with bitcoinjs, but you are trying to use Bitcoin Core’s wallet RPCs to get information on them? The Bitcoin Core wallet RPCs can only provide information on the Bitcoin Core wallet that is loaded. How would it know about a wallet that was created with bitcoinjs? To interact with wallets created by bitcoinjs, you should probably use bitcoinjs methods
